# Right extensions along right adjoints

Tags: category-theory, 2-categories

I'm reading *The Formal Theory of Monads* by Ross Street, and I am stumped at the fourth theorem. It seems that its proof has been elided, so I tried to come up with one myself.

This theorem requires basic knowledge of 2-categories. Before I state the theorem, I'll define the notion of a right extension.

In a 2-category $\mathbf{C}$, Let $F : B \to X$ and $P : B \to A$ be 1-cells. A *right extension* of $F$ along $P$ is a 1-cell $\Sigma_P F : A \to X$ and a 2-cell $\sigma : (\Sigma_P F) P \to F$ such that any 2-cell $\theta : G \to \Sigma_P F$ with codomain $\Sigma_P F$ is uniquely determined by the composite $\sigma \cdot \theta P$.

Now, here is the statement of theorem 4.

**Theorem 4**
If $P : B \to A$ is a 1-cell with left adjoint $Q : A \to B$, and if $\epsilon : QP \to 1$ is the counit of the adjunction, then any 1-cell $F : B \to X$ has a right extension along $P$ given by the 1-cell $FQ : A \to X$ and the 2-cell $F \epsilon : (FQ) P \to F$.

If I understand correctly, it's asking me to prove that for all 1-cells $U : A \to X$ and 2-cells $\theta_1,\theta_2 : U \to FQ$, if $F \epsilon \cdot \theta_1 P = F \epsilon \cdot \theta_2 P$ then $\theta_1 = \theta_2$. The triangle laws for adjunctions don't seem to apply here since there is no unit. Additionally, commutativity of vertical and horizontal composition doesn't seem to apply either.

Can someone explain how to prove this theorem?

Comment: It is a general fact, valid in every 2-category, that the left adjoint $f$ in an adjunction $f\dashv g$ is the absolute right extension of the identity along $g$; you know what is a right extension. "Absolute" means "preserve by every functor/1-cell". Don't quit if you don't succeed the first time, it's a slightly tricky proof (the notation is heavy). I had a similar problem years ago, if you look here or on MO you might find a question of mine where a completely explicit proof is given :-)